# free an area of memory containing structure

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I'm dealing with structure and pointer.
I've a doubt about how `free` works, considering this code:

```
struct point{
    int id;
    double* values;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct point *dataset = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct point));
    ....
    free(dataset + 7);

}
```

`free` will free just the `sizeof(struct point)` between `dataset + 7` and `dataset + 8` or will free all from `dataset + 7` to the end?

And about `realloc`, doing something like this:

```
struct point{
    int id;
    double* values;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct point *dataset = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct point));
    ....
    free(dataset + 9);

    dataset = realloc(dataset, 9 * sizeof(struct point));

}
```

Is this approach wrong? If I remove the point in `dataset[9]` from `dataset` I have to `free` and then `realloc`? Or it just need `realloc`?

Comment: From [`free` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free): "The behavior is **undefined** if the value of `ptr` does not equal a value returned earlier by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, or `aligned_alloc()`." Therefore, calling `free` with `dataset + 7` (which is different from `dataset` that was returned by `malloc()`) causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The call to `malloc(10 * sizeof(struct point))` is similar to creating an array of `struct point`. And just like an array, you can't remove individual elements from it. *Unlike* an array you can reallocate the memory, to make it larger or smaller. If you make it smaller, that's effectively removing the last element(s) of the array.

Comment: You can only `free` the exact thing created by `malloc`.  Anything else is likely to crash the program.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong. You cant realloc `free`ed memory. You need also to save the returned pointer to the temporary variable to avoid memory leaks if `realloc` fails.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct point *dataset = malloc(10 * sizeof(*dataset));
    struct point *tmp;

    tmp = realloc(dataset, 9 * sizeof(*dataset));
    if(tmp)
    {
        dataset = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        /* handle allocation errors*/
    }

    /* .... */
   
    //when dataset is not needed anymore
    free(dataset);

}
```

Note: it is better to use objects, not types in the `sizeof` (as in my example). Also always **check** the result of memory allocation as it may fail.